# how to fix 'T' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable' compile error

Tags: c#

I need to check if a generic type parameter `T` is `MyEntity` or a subclass of it.

Code below causes this compiler error:

```
'T' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable'
```

how to fix?

```
public class MyEntity { }

static void Test<T>()
{
    // Error    34  'T' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable'
    if (T is MyEntity)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `IsAssignableFrom` method on `Type` to check whether one `Type` can be assigned to another.

```
if (typeof(MyEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
```

Note: if you want that `T` can **only** be `MyEntity` or it's subclasses, you can define generic constraint, like this:

```
static void Test<T>() where T : MyEntity
{

}
```

And the code like `Test<object>()` won't even compile

---

You can check `IsAssignableFrom` with this code:

```
public static void F<T>()
{
    var isAssignable = typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));

    Console.WriteLine ("{0} is {1} IEnumerable", typeof(T).Name, isAssignable ? "" : "not");
}
```

Examples:

```
F<IList>();       //prints IList is IEnumerable
F<IEnumerable>(); //prints IEnumerable is IEnumerable
F<object>();      //prints object is not IEnumerable
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was just checking it with `IEnumerable` and `List`

Comment: I dont understand comment. T may be MyEntity or its subclass like 'public class Order: MyEntity'  or sublcass of Order of some level. Will this check return true in all those cases ?

Comment: @Andrus yes, see examples in answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer with generic constraint definition. Please see if it feet your need

Comment: Thank you. ASP.NET cache needs to be invalidated if table in database (entity) changes. Other types may also be passed (cached) so compile time check is not possible. Your code is used to check if entity is passed and then `HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key,cacheobject,
                    new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(null,typeof(T).Name))` is called for cache invalidation on table data change

Comment: I dont need to check for interfaces. So `IsSubclassOf()` is better, isn't it ?

Comment: well, don't restrict yourself from usage of interfaces. `IsAssignableFrom` works perfectly for classes and interfaces, so I don't see why do you want to use `IsSubclassOf`

Comment: Entities are derived from MyEntity base class. MyEntity is class and it is not interface. Using this knowledge it looks like IsSubclassOf can safely used also

Comment: suppose your `MyEntity` has a derived class `MyEntityDerived` which also implements `IDerivedEntity` and you want to pass `IDerivedEntity` somewhere, instead of `MyEntityDerived`.

Comment: Yes it this case only your answer works. However in my case entities are always derived from MyEntity class